# Strange files in /tmp/

Tags: redhat, rhel5, agent

I have never seen this files in RedHat before.

```
/tmp/orbit-root
/tmp/ssh-KEskO14981/agent.14981
/tmp/keyring-OuVrZn/sock
```

What could it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/tmp/orbit-root
```

If your computer gets its IP-address by DHCP, this is probably `dhclient`.  Check with `lsof -n | grep orbit` as root.

```
/tmp/ssh-KEskO14981/agent.14981
```

Looks like the ssh-agent-process.  This makes it possible to cache your passphrase when you attempt to do ssh-logins on servers using a key with passphrase, so you don't have to type it in every time.

```
/tmp/keyring-OuVrZn/sock
```

Looks like the gnome-keyring-daemon.  This stores several credentials for you.  This is the socket other applications talk through when they want to fetch credentials from it.

Comment: Can the second file used by malware or rootkit? I have some suspicions about it. Because this file didn't exist there before.

Comment: Probably not Malware - it's normal as long as someone is logged in to Gnome.  Do you have an ssh-agent running (`ps aux | grep ssh-agent`)? Check if it has the files open with `lsof -n | grep ssh-agent` as root. My guess is that the agent.14981-file is the unix-socket the agent uses.  Regardless, it's safe to kill it off - the only consequence is that ssh can't cache the passphrase of ssh-keys. (The ssh-agent may also run without Gnome, it just has to be started somehow)